# execute firefox profile from delphi with environment variables

Tags: delphi, firefox, environment-variables, profile

To execute profiles in firefox I use this bat code

```
@echo off
set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1

"D:\Archivos de Programa\Firefox7\firefox.exe" -p "Light"

set MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1
```

how can I make the same thing from delphi?

I did this, but i don't know how to set the environment variables

```
var
  app:string;
begin
  app := '"D:\Archivos de Programa\Firefox7\firefox.exe" -p "Light"';
  WinExec(PChar(app), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

i solved

here is the code

```
function SetEnvVarValue(const VarName, VarValue: string): Integer;
begin
  // Simply call API function
  if SetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName), PChar(VarValue)) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := GetLastError;
end;
```

so to use only that:

```
app := '"D:\Archivos de Programa\Firefox7\firefox.exe" -p "Light"';
SetEnvVarValue('MOZ_NO_REMOTE', '1');
WinExec(PChar(app), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
SetEnvVarValue('MOZ_NO_REMOTE', '1');
```

and that is :)

Comment: I quess the "correct" solution would be to use the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Comment: You're stuck in ancient times in multiple ways. First, WinExec has been deprecated since the release of Windows 95. Use CreateProcess or ShellExecute instead. Second, the MOZ_NO_REMOTE environment variable was superseded by the `-no-remote` command-line option in Firefox 2 around 2006. Also, why are you setting the variable to the same value twice?

Comment: Please put your solution in the *answer* section. Otherwise, it looks to everyone else like you're still waiting for an answer to your question, and those who don't read your question carefully will think there's something *wrong* with your solution because it appears as part of the question instead of as an answer.

Comment: @Rob, d'oh, now it looks like I've stolen your comment into my answer, but I found the `-no-remote` command-line option about 20 minutes ago and I've been writing my answer without seeing your comment (deleting...)

Comment: @Rob, post your comment as the answer; you were faster with it ;)

Comment: My comment is not an answer, @Tlama. It doesn't tell how to launch anything with environment variables. Robert's *own* edit contains the answer: use or wrap `SetEnvironmentVariable`. My comment is saying that he never really needed an answer to this question in the first place, but that doesn't help anyone else who later wants to know how to set environment variables for something *other than* Firefox's "no remote" mode.